# ¿Abrir y cerrar conexión base de datos en cada function? Java8, Tomcat8

Tags: java, tomcat

Estoy mejorando el rendimiento de un proyecto bastante complejo. Creo que tengo un problema de ineficiencia. Cuando se realizar una consulta a la base de datos dentro de una función, se llama a una clase statica para que devuelve una conexión. Pero veo que cada vez se realiza la conexión.

Por ejemplo, en esta function:

```
    public Boolean exist_unique_id_external(){

            Boolean result = false;

            String sql = "SELECT external_locata FROM reserves_locata ";
            sql += "WHERE id_agencia = ? ";
            sql += "AND external_locata = ? ";
            try{
                // prepare
                Connection cn = ConfiguracioOBE.getConnectionReadOnly();
                PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                st.setInt(1, agency.getId());
                st.setString(2, unique_id_external);

                // execute
                ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();

                // result
                result = rs.first();

                // close
                rs.close();
                st.close();
                cn.close();

            }catch (Exception e) {
                logger.info(Main.xml);
                logger.error("Exception", e);
            }
            return (result);
        }
```

La función ConfiguracioOBE.getConnectionReadOnly() hace los siguiente:

```
    public static Connection getConnectionReadOnly(){
        Connection cn = null;
        try{
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://"+props.getProperty("db_readonly_host")+"/"+props.getProperty("db_readonly_databasename")+"?useEncoding=true&useConfigs=maxPerformance&characterEncoding="+props.getProperty("db_readonly_encoding")+"&characterSetResults="+props.getProperty("db_readonly_encoding"),props.getProperty("db_readonly_username"),props.getProperty("db_readonly_password"));         
        }catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return cn; 
    }
```

La aplicación es un servlet, que recibe millones de peticiones XML diaras. ¿Hay alguan forma que no tenga que hacer DriverManager.getConnection en cada función? He probado varias soluciones pero no me funcionan bien. No ser si es correcto que la classe ConfiguracioOBE sea estatica.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: No tengo tiempo de escribir una respuesta ahora, pero aquí tienes una explicación clara de lo que necesitas: [un pool de conexiones](http://chuwiki.chuidiang.org/index.php?title=Pool_de_conexiones)

Comment: correcto, esta es la situación exacta que me encuentro. voy a probar usando un pool. gracias

Comment: Si nadie te responde antes de que soluciones tu problema, puedes autorresponderte añadiendo tu solución, eso siempre es bienvenido aquí :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La solución es usar un 'pool' o banco de conexiones pero no es necesario que programes el tuyo propio. El mismo Tomcat ofrece un banco de conexiones JDBC (JDBC connection pool) que puedes configurar y evitar manejar toda la complejidad de mantenerlo tu mismo.

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class EjemploSencillo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"); // aquí pones el nombre del servidor de base de datos, puerto y nombre.
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // investiga cuáles son los parámetros para tu marca de base de datos. Este es MySQL.
        p.setUsername("root");
        p.setPassword("password");
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(100);
        p.setInitialSize(10);
        p.setMaxWait(10000);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(10);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors(
                "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;" +
                        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");
        DataSource fuenteDeDatos = new DataSource(); // tu 'datasource'
        fuenteDeDatos.setPoolProperties(p);

        Connection cn = null;
        try {
            cn = fuenteDeDatos.getConnection();
            String sql = " SELECT external_locata FROM reserves_locata WHERE id_agencia = ? AND external_locata = ? ";
            PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setInt(1, agency.getId());
            st.setString(2, unique_id_external);

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            int cnt = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println((cnt++) + ". Host:" + rs.getString("Host") +
                        " User:" + rs.getString("User") + " Password:" + rs.getString("Password"));
            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } finally {
            if (cn != null) try {
                cn.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {// ignora o maneja la excepción}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ten éste ciclo en mente para optimizar las conexiones (sólo necesitas un Singleton):

1. Navegador pide URL.
2. Servlet recibe URL.
3. Servlet pide el Singleton de tu fuenteDeDatos.
4. Servlet pide una conexión de la fuenteDeDatos.
5. Servlet usa la conexión para accessar el banco de datos.
6. Servlet cierra la conexión (regresándola automáticamente al pool de conexiones).
7. Servlet sirve la respuesta (response) al navegador.

Comment: si, pero en mi caso trabajo con un servlet, es decir, tengo la finciones init(), doGet(), doPost(), destroy(). Entiendo que el  DataSource fuenteDeDatos lo tendré que instanciar dentro del init(). Es decir, solamente se cargará una vez al iniciar el tomcat. I para poder acceder desde el doGet() deberé ponerlo como static,,, correcto? .. Pongo código de ejemplo debajo...

Comment: @maik No, ese ejemplo que pusiste iniciaría el pool cada vez que hay un request, es decir, cada vez que un navegador pida el URL de ese servlet. Necesitarías usar un Singleton (que se inicializa sólo una vez) y, si no quieres usar un framework como struts2 o spring, deberás implementar una variable ThreadLocal y un Contexto para lograr el mismo efecto.

Comment: en mi caso no es así, he comprobado escribiendo en el logs file, y el código que tengo en el init() solamente se ejecuta una vez al iniciar el tomcat. Luego, por muchas peticiones que haga con distintos navegadores, sessiones, ordenadores, etc... no vuelve a ejecutarse
Supongo que se debe poder configurar segun se desee. gracias igualmente

Comment: @maik Sí, tienes razón, `init()` es llamado por Tomcat sólo una vez, lo estaba confundiendo con `contextInitialized`. También puedes implementar `destroy()` para cerrar la conexión limpiamente cuando detengas la aplicación, de esa forma cuando reinicies la aplicación muchas veces no tendrás fuga de recursos (leaks).

Answer (score 0):

¿¿¿Seria correcto algo así???

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.PoolProperties;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;

public class Main extends HttpServlet {

    public static DataSource fuenteDeDatos = null 

    public Main() {}

    public void init() throws ServletException {
    try{
    PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
        p.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"); // aquí pones el nombre del servidor de base de datos, puerto y nombre.
        p.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); // investiga cuáles son los parámetros para tu marca de base de datos. Este es MySQL.
        p.setUsername("root");
        p.setPassword("password");
        p.setJmxEnabled(true);
        p.setTestWhileIdle(false);
        p.setTestOnBorrow(true);
        p.setValidationQuery("SELECT 1");
        p.setTestOnReturn(false);
        p.setValidationInterval(30000);
        p.setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(30000);
        p.setMaxActive(100);
        p.setInitialSize(10);
        p.setMaxWait(10000);
        p.setRemoveAbandonedTimeout(60);
        p.setMinEvictableIdleTimeMillis(30000);
        p.setMinIdle(10);
        p.setLogAbandoned(true);
        p.setRemoveAbandoned(true);
        p.setJdbcInterceptors(
                "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;" +
                        "org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer");

    fuenteDeDatos = new DataSource(); // tu 'datasource'
        fuenteDeDatos.setPoolProperties(p);

    }catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new ServletException(ex);
    }
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {
            cn = fuenteDeDatos.getConnection();
            String sql = " SELECT external_locata FROM reserves_locata WHERE id_agencia = ? AND external_locata = ? ";
            PreparedStatement st = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
            st.setInt(1, agency.getId());
            st.setString(2, unique_id_external);

            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            int cnt = 1;
            while (rs.next()) {
                System.out.println((cnt++) + ". Host:" + rs.getString("Host") +
                        " User:" + rs.getString("User") + " Password:" + rs.getString("Password"));
            }
            rs.close();
            st.close();
        } finally {
            if (cn != null) try {
                cn.close();
            } catch (Exception ignore) {// ignora o maneja la excepción}
            }
        }

    }

}
```