# Optimizar codigo java y conexiones mysql

Tags: java, mysql

Estoy desarrollado una aplicación de escritorio en Java y uso conexiones a *MySQL*, por el momento es de forma local, pero he notado que usa demasiado mi procesador, revisando los procesos abiertos de *MySQL*, pude encontrar que deja muchos procesos abiertos, en estado "sleep", he intentado hacer una secuencia para detenerlas, pero me cierra la conexión a la base de datos y por lógica ya no hace ninguna operación desde la aplicación.

¿Alguna idea para optimizar los procesos que realizo?

Uso una clase para conectar que es así :

```
public class Conexion {

    private static String servidor = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/skywater?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull";
    private static String user = "root";
    private static String pass = "pass";
    private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static Connection conexion;

    public Conexion() {
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(servidor, user, pass);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error al establecer conexion con base de datos \n Contacte Servicio: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection() {
        return conexion;
    }

    public Connection getClosedConnection() throws SQLException {
        conexion.close();
        System.out.println("Conexion cerrada");
        return conexion;
    }
}
```

Y otra clase para cada tipo de operación en la base de datos que contiene diferentes métodos por ejemplo un método de consulta:

```
public class OperacionesDB {
    Conexion conector = new Conexion();

    Connection con = conector.getConnection();
    Statement st;
    ...
}
```

Y a mi parecer, el método que me esta generando muchos procesos en *MySQL* es el siguiente :

```
public DefaultTableModel consultaGeneral(String tabla, String columna, String valor) {

    System.out.println(tabla);
    DefaultTableModel modelo = new DefaultTableModel();

    String seleccion = "SELECT * FROM " + tabla + " WHERE " + columna + " LIKE '%" + valor + "%';";
    try {
        Statement ejecutor = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = ejecutor.executeQuery(seleccion);
        String nvo[] = new String[rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount()];
        for (int j = 1; j <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); j++) {
            modelo.addColumn(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(j));
        }

        while (rs.next()) {
            for (int i = 1; i <= modelo.getColumnCount(); i++)
                nvo[i - 1] = rs.getString(i);
            modelo.addRow(nvo);
        }

        ejecutor.close();
        //con.close();
        rs.close();

        return modelo;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Error en consulta general " + e.getMessage());
        return modelo;
    }
}
```

Esta consulta se activa al entrar a la aplicación y esta para muchas *JInternalFrame*, y se activa también con un *JText* cuando se preciosa una tecla para generar la búsqueda.

Comment: Deberías poner tu código aquí para poder ver cómo gestionas las conexiones. Te aconsejo que hagas el [tour] de StackOverflow en español para aprender qué consideramos una buena pregunta y despues puedes [edit] tu pregunta y añadir un [mcve]

Comment: Seguramente dejes conexiones abiertas, como dice @PabloLozano muestranos código para poder ayudarte mejor

Comment: Hola Isaí, sube el resto de código para poder ayudarte.

Comment: Esos sleep se quedan por una propiedad de mysql, lo que tienes que hacer es modificar esas variables en mysql y listo (siempre que no tengas errores en tu código): http://www.elmundoenbits.com/2012/07/timeout-en-conexiones-mysql.html#.W866kmgzaUk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

He podido resolver mi problema utilizando un "pool" de conexiones, por el tipo de consulta que utilizaba generaba muchos procesos en Mysql, utilizando un "pool" optimizó de forma significativa dichos procesos, se pudieron reducir.

Dejo el link de un tema que me ayudó:

[abrir/cerrar conexiones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/118200/abrir-y-cerrar-conexi%C3%B3n-base-de-datos-en-cada-function-java8-tomcat8)

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, Revisar [answer]. "Los enlaces a recursos externos son aceptables pero no se te vaya a olvidar agregar el contexto alrededor de los enlaces. "

Comment: En resumen: las dos respuestas apuntan al mismo problema. Estabas abriendo un montón de instancias de conexión y nunca liberabas los recursos. El GC sólo va a disponer de esas instancias de Statement, ResultSet y conexion si las haces null. Las conexiones ni siquiera las cerrabas. El pool maneja eso por su cuenta.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Connection conn = null;

public Connection getConexion() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/db?user=root&password=");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return conn;
}

public Connection closeConn() {
    try {
        conn.close();
        conn = null;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    return conn;
}
```

Comment: Un solo metodo hace lo que estas haciendo con dos metodos tanto para conectar como para retornar la conexion, y para optimizar ese select * from por practica deberias usar procedimientos almacenados ayuda tanto para codigo mas legible y ayudar a acelerar las sentencias en la base de datos